# How can I manage to delete only 1 line at a time and not the whole text in GUI tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Good day everyone, I am david a 9 years old, and I would like to ask some question related to GUI.. Can anyone please help me, how can I manage to delete only 1 line and not the whole text.

here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x240")

def clear():
    Text.delete("1.0","end")

Text = tk.Text(root, height=10)
Text.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Delete 1 line",command=clear)

button.pack()

Text.get("1.0", "end")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If there are more than one line of text, then which line do you want to delete?

Comment: I would like to delete only the upper one or the first line or i have an idea on using an else if statement typing a number which part would like to delete..

Comment: If you just want to delete the first line, use `Text.delete('1.0', '2.0')`.

Comment: Thank you so so much sir  for the help